# What is the advantage of having multiple File groups for a database?

Tags: sql-server

I am having a relatively small database today, and I am expecting that my db size will grow drastically in coming months. What are the precautions I should take to get better performance when the db size grows larger? In this case, will splitting the primary file group of  my database in to multiple secondary solves my problem?  Please advise.

Answer (score 5):

Splitting a database across multiple filegroups permits you to take advantage of the I/O bandwidth for each physical device / path that you've placed filegroups onto. Placing multiple filegroups on the same physical disk / LUN wouldn't give you any advantage, but placing them on multiple disks / LUNs can give you a multiple of the bandwidth of a single disk / LUN (provided the underlying physical connectivity allows it).

You can get very detailed, storing parts of the database that are less frequently acccessed onto slower "nearline" types of media, and keeping the higher activity pieces (very heavily used indexes, tables, etc) onto the higher-cost faster storage.

You're not necessarily going to get significantly worse performance as your database gets bigger, depending on your design. A good indexing strategy can allow growth of the underlying database without dramatically increasing query times. If you do find that you're saturating the I/O that hosts your filegroups then adding addt'l filegroups on addt'l disks / LUNs can increase your performance. The key to deciding if multiple filegroups is going to help you is going to be in monitoring I/O performance. Multiple filegroups won't do anything to help you if you're CPU bound or choked for RAM. Filegroups only really help with I/O utilization, which is only one axis of comprehensive performance monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer by @Evan. However there are additional benefits to using multiple filegroups in addition to I/O. Check out this article on the list of key indicators to move to multiple file groups: [Using Multiple Filegroups in a SQL Server Database](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=967)

- When individual tables take more than 10% of used space
- When regular maintenance on a big filegroup is taking too long, so many smaller filegroups will fit your requirements better
- Among other reasons